# The drawStarsStairs challenge

Tags: javascript

I need a code that would print a pattern of # depending on what I type into the console. I also want the code to use three for loops and a function.

For example, if I type in something like drawStarStairs(5), I want a certain pattern of stars to be printed onto the console. Like this:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

If I type in drawStarStairs(3), it would be like this:

```
#
##
###
```

If I type in drawStarsStairs(2), it would be like this:

```
#
##
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a zero effort homework dump.

Comment: Also downvoted it, just asking for a solution at a problem without even having tried anything is not the purpose of stackoverflow nor the purpose of homeworks. That's a bit sad people still answer this kind of "questions"

Comment: How do you know I haven't tried anything? For your imformation, I have tried for around 1 hour and 30 min. I'm not a lazy person. I'm having difficulty with this problem and I need help. I'm not ordering people to help me. I'm asking them. Also, this is not homework. I'm doing coding as a hobby, and I admit I'm not that good at it. Isn't that what stackoverflow is for? To get help with coding questions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function draw(inputNum) {
var pound="";
for(var i = 1; i <=inputNum; i++ ) {
        for(j = 0; j<i;j++) {
             pound+="#";
         }  
            pound+="\n";
    }
    console.log(pound)
}
draw(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

you can try like this:

```js
//function defination
function drawStarStairs(item) {
 for (i = 1; i <= item; i++) { 
  var hash = "";
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
   hash += "#";
  }
  console.log(hash);
 }
}

//calling function
drawStarStairs(5)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function drawStarStairs(_rows) {
    hashString = '';
    for (i = 0; i < _rows; i++) { 
        console.log(hashString = hashString + '#');
    }
}

drawStarStairs(5);
drawStarStairs(3);
drawStarStairs(2);
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, you might consider adding an explanation to make it a good answer.

Comment: Absolutely @BDL

It's the easiest route to the solution. 
I have used a basic function which passes the parameter of how many rows you require. As the function is initialised it sets `hashString = '';` which is where you will build the '#' output. The question suggests using 3 for loops, well we use one, inside this function which is called three times. As the loop loops over the rows it concatenates an extra '#' to the `hashString` variable and therefore you see the anticipated steps output in the `console.log`.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was unclear: You should edit your answer to contain the explanation why/how this code solves the problem. In general, answering such low quality questions that are simple "write my code for me" questions is not wanted at SO (which might be the reason for the down-votes).